# how to read authorization request header from nginx

Tags: nginx

I have installed nginx 1.6 and how to read authorization request header from nginx,  if authorization header is present i need to forward to success page 'success.html', if  authorization header it is not present in the request i need to forward to 'error.html' how can we do this in nginx